# Can googleVis functions be used with custom maps?

Tags: r, google-maps, googlevis

GoogleVis seems to connect to google maps to operate. Is it possible to use custom maps, such as shapefiles that could be read via OGR.

```
library(rgdal)
counties.rg <- readOGR(".", "kih1897m_region", encoding="UTF-8")
```

So, is there a way to work with `counties.rg` with `gvisGeoMap()` function. The region parameter allows a way to zoom in, but sometimes more detailed maps are needed.

This could also be possible by adding a layer on top of the default map via global coordinates. Is there a way to do this? I would add the shape files, but I suppose the question has a really general answer.